# How can I replace PDF content of a window?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I'm displaying a PDF inside another window by using base64 encoded data and this is working perfectly using

```
this.pdfWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
this.pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe id='pdf_frame' width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(res)+"'></iframe>")
```

But I would like to be able to update the content of this window and change the PDF file that is represented there.

I've tried to do another `write` but this is just appending the other PDF below the current one.

I've tried this as well:

```
this.pdfWindow.document.getElementById('pdf_frame').innerHTML = newContent;
```

Nothing happened.

I've also tried removing and re-appending the frame without success:

```
this.pdfWindow.document.removeChild(this.pdfWindow.document.getElementById('pdf_frame'));
this.pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe id='pdf_frame' width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(res)+"'></iframe>");
```

Still nothing happening.

I'm surely missing something but can't find it.

Thanks for futures answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.pdfWindow.document.removeChild(this.pdfWindow.document.getElementById('pdf_frame'));
```

This code won't work because that element is not a direct child of `document`. Instead do something like this:

```
var oldPdf = this.pdfWindow.document.getElementById('pdf_frame');
oldPdf.parentElement.removeChild(oldPdf);
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the tip.. Long time since I didn't code in javascript and I didn't think of this. I'll give you the bounty but need to wait for 24h.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were almost there.

You don't have to remove the iframe and you can update content in it.
Please have a look next URL regarding Data URI.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Change next to

```
//browser will read pdfData as Data URI not HTML, thus .innerHTML would not work.
this.pdfWindow.document.getElementById('pdf_frame').innerHTML = newContent;
```

to next using **.src**

```
var newContent = `data:application/pdf;base64, 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`
this.pdfWindow.document.getElementById('pdf_frame').src = newContent;
```